# PHP curl in a functions does not return antyhing

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have an API url that needs to be executed, it returns either the state of something or an id that you can check the state and get the result based on the id.
 I wrote a function to execute CURL, but it does not return any results..

```
    <?php

    function curlCommand($initialCall = false, $URL){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      "API-KEY: keykeykey",
      "token: blahlbahlbah"
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if($initialCall == false){
      $response = (array)json_decode($response);
    }else{//initial call. (the response is not json, it's a string incorporated into quotations, we need to take out the quotations and use that response in the url to make a new call.)
      $response = str_replace('"','',$response);
    }  

    curl_close($ch);  
    return $response;

}

$init = curlCommand(true,"https://url.com/command/");

echo "init: ";
print_r($init);
echo "\n";
```

print_r($init) - does not return anything. Can someone elaborate?

if executed as curl not inside the function - everything works as normal.

Comment: What's the output from curl_error() ?

Comment: @SorinLascu never checked it, should I call it inside the function or after the function?

Comment: curl_error($ch) before you call curl_close

Comment: Hi @PaaPs, your code above works for me. I get the following output:

`init: <html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body bgcolor=white>
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @DanielSposito Thanks, I'll check the call urls, maybe I'm calling the wrong ones

Comment: It would also be worth trying `var_dump($response)` right after the `curl_exec()`, and right before the `return`.

Comment: @zenzelezz yup, already figured it out though. The problem was bad API call, and some other mistakes I've left in the code.. Everything working now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bad request URL passed passed into the function.